# Do different all packets of a single SSH session have same TTL?

Tags: ssh

I was asked this question and I wasn't really sure of the answer. 
Basically we have an `SSH` session between a server and a client (we are on the network and we can sample the traffic between 2 routers for example).
Do all the packets of this session have the same TTL ?

My first answer would be no, the packets coming from the server (resp. the client) would have the TTL associated to the OS and also depends on the routing (number of hops).

Is my answer correct?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question, but a networking question

Comment: The hop limit of packets you receive may change as a result of changes in routing. And the sender is free to change hop limit as they desire throughout a connection, but there is rarely a reason to do so.